# Rails create multiple rows from one form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails app that has building and floors models

```
class Building < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :floors
end

class Floor < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :building
end
```

In my building form I want to ask the user how many floors the building has, and then when the building is created I want to add that many floors.

So the form would look like so:

```
<%= form_with(model: building, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if building.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(building.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this building from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
        <% building.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
          <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :" How many floors does the building have" %>
    <%= form.number :floors %> * not sure how to do this
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Note I don't want the number of floors saved on the building model, it just creates the number of floors the user specified.

So if I created a building called "Walts Place" and said it has 10 floors it would create: Walts Place with id:1, and 10 floors with the building_id of 1.

Does that make sense?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Update:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2019_07_30_093037) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "buildings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.float "distancetocondensors"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
  end

  create_table "floors", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "building_id", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.index ["building_id"], name: "index_floors_on_building_id"
  end

  add_foreign_key "floors", "buildings"
end
```

Comment: How does your schema look like ?
In this line 
` <%= form.number :floors %> * not sure how to do this`
You are passing the `floors` which is not a column in `building` but another table with a relation to `building` model through `has_many :floors`.

where as `name` supposly is a column in `building`.

Comment: Hi @Glig Him I think i pretty clearly state that I do not want the number of floors as a qty field in the building model... I want it to .build or .create the floors... updated to show schema

Comment: In that case, I think I'll go and override the `create` action in `buildings_controller.rb`. Use the `params[:number]` to create `n` associated floors. You could also use `nested forms` but they are much more complex for that use case.

Comment: @Glig Him I really appreciate that, but I am not sure how to put that into something i can use? could you put it in an answer? I am thinking that will be something like if building.save building.floors.each do |n| n.floors.create but i really have no idea... hence the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify it in your building controller in create action.

```
def create
  @building = Building.new(building_params)
  if @building.save
    floors = params[:number].to_i
    floors.times do
      Floor.create(building: @building)
    end 
    redirect_to building_path
  else
    redirect_to error
  end
end
```

in your form add a field for number of floor without erb

```
<%= form_with(model: building, local: true) do |form| %>
  <% if building.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(building.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this building 
       from being saved:</h2>

     <ul>
       <% building.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
        <li><%= message %></li>
        <% end %>
       </ul>
      </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="field">
         <%= form.label :name %>
          <%= form.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <label> How many floors does the building have</label>
        <input type="number" name="number"/>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= form.submit %>
      </div>
   <% end %>
```

Comment: "<%= form.number :floors %> this will give you an error because there is no field with floor for building model"

That is not true, you can use custom fields safely

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`nested attributes`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) to help you here.

First, in your `Building` model add:

```rb
has_many :floors
accepts_nested_attributes_for :floors
```

Then in your `BuildingController`'s `create` action do:

```rb
class BuildingController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def create
    floors_amount = params[:building][:floors] || 0
    building_params = params.require(:building).permit(:name).merge({
      # just fill floors array with empty hashes since `id` will be added automatically
      floors_attributes: (1..floors_amount).to_a.fill({})
    })
    @building = Building.create(building_params)
    if @buildnig.errors
      render :new # show the form page with an error
    else
      redirect_to @building # or whenever you want to redirect
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

The advantage here is that it wraps the creation of building and floors into a transaction so if something goes wrong it will rollback all changes. I.e. there won't be a case where new Building is inserted into DB but floors didn't due to some error during their creation.

Another convenience here is that if some validation error appears either on `building` or on any of the `floor` then it will be set into `building.errors`. Means you can easily do `render :new` in the case of errors to display them.

#### Note:

I see that in your form view you access Building instance as `building`. So I'm not really sure how you pass it to this view.
In my example I saved building into `@building` variable so that in this view form you will have to access it as `@building`. I believe in your `new` action in `BuildingController` you should set it to `@building` as well:

```rb
class BuildingController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def new
    @building = Building.new
  end
  ...
end
```

And in your view you will access it as `@building` then, not `building`.

Hope, that makes sense